# URL rewriting - removing folder structure displayed in URL - AngularJS+PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, url-rewriting, angular-ui-router

I have a web-site created in angularJS-php. I have two different index pages. One of them is "index.php" and the other one is "index.html".

I have a href in login.tpm.html

```
<a href="/member/somePage">
```

which looks for action in index.php. In index.php,for given URL/request, I am navigating to angular's index.html . In angular index.html, I am using ui-view which renders angular states. 
index.php:

```
 $app->get('/member/somePage', function () use ($app) {
      $app->response()->redirect('folder1/sub-folder2/index.html?v=0301b');
    });
```

The issue here is, URL created is

```
http://localhost:443/folder1/sub-folder2/index.html?v=0131b#!/PageName
```

whereas I want url to be

```
http://localhost:443/PageName
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this. How can I remove folder structure from URL

Answer (score 0):

Below is the fix.

We will use the $locationProvider module and set html5Mode to true.

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller : mainController
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

To link around your application using relative links, you will need to set a  in the  of your document.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="/">
</head>
```